# Selenium with GeckoDriver don't work on ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, geckodriver

I'm trying to use `GeckoDriver` in `asp.net core` (`dotnet new webapi`). But, It's always throw exceptions:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to start browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error (SessionNotCreated)'
```

I tried to use with .net core console (`dotnet new console`), and It's working fine.

One more thing, I use `ChromeDriver` in `asp.net core` still fine.

Why? What difference between `asp.net core` and `.net core console`? And why `ChromeDriver` is working bold?

This is infomation of my project:

```
Dotnet version: .net core 3.0
Firefox version: 75.0 (64 bit)
Selenium version: 3.141.0
GeckoDriver version: 0.26.0.1
```

Thank you

Update 1:
Maybe It's answers for my question.
I don't know exactly why. 
But, `GeckoDriver` run fine on Project Profile.

By default, when I F5 my project, It's run with `IIS Express`. I switched to Profiles of project (It will run in `https://localhost:5001` by default).
And It's working!

Comment: check the version compatibility of your `geckodriver`  and  `firefox` browser??

Comment: Yup, It's compatibility!

Comment: can you post the piece of code you have done?

Comment: Just ```IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();```

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -2):

This might be a longshot, but any updates here? I am running into the same issue. ChromeDriver and EdgeDriver work with ASP.Net Core 5 and 6, but FirefoxDriver throws the above error. I've tried with both the 32 and 64 bit versions of FirefoxDriver.

Also when I switch the profile to use project profile, it works. The project profile uses the commandName: Project option which uses the Kestrel web server as opposed to IISExpress. So it seems like IIS is the culprit? I can get my application to run locally, but when I deploy it to a web server, it errors out and I'm assuming it's because it can run under IIS?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).